# Setting and getting global variable in JavaScript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to work out why I am getting `undefined` data type on `printName()`. So how we can update a global variable trough a function (like a Setter) function and get access the updated value via other functions if needed.

```
$(function () {
    var name;

    function setName() {
        name = "TestName";
    }

    function printName() {
        alert(name);
    }
    printName();
});
```

Comment: You don't call the `setName` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't set the name using `setName()`. function. in other words you never called setName()

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var name;

function setName() {
    name = "TestName";
}

function printName() {
    alert(name);
}
    setName();
    printName();
});
```